# Testing equality between two heterogeneous values

Tags: haskell, ghc, existential-type

I'm using the `-XExistentialQuantification` GHC extension to create a heterogeneous container for values of a specific type class (`Shape`):

```
-- Container type
data Object = forall a. Shape a => Object a

-- 'Shape' class. Methods not important
class Eq s => Shape s where
    doStuff :: s -> s
```

Given that all instances of `Shape` are also instances of `Eq`, is there a way to make `Object` an instance of `Eq` as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's possible if you add a `Typeable` constraint:

```
import Data.Typeable

data Object = forall a. (Shape a, Typeable a) => Object a

instance Eq Object where
  Object x == Object y =
    case cast y of
      Just y' -> x == y'
      Nothing -> False
```

Here, `cast y` will return `Just y'` if the desired type of `y'` (inferred from the use of `==` with `x`) matches the actual type of `y`, and `Nothing` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. I had a feeling Typeable might be involved but I'd never actually used it before.

Comment: `Object x == Object y = Just x == cast y`

Answer (score 2):

No, because `Eq a` says you can compare two values of type `a`. An `Eq` instance on your object would allow arbitrary pairs of values (of any type that is an instance of `Shape`) to be compared.

If I have `Shape Int` and `Shape Bool` instances, how can I compare `Object True` with `Object 1` for equality?

Answer (score 1):

A value of a type which implements `Eq` can only be compared with another value of the same type - not of any other type that implements `Eq`. So if you have two values of different types, you can't compare them even if they're both instances of `Shape` (and thus `Eq`). Therefore it's also impossible to have an `Eq` instance for `Object` as an `Object` can contain values of different types - at least using the types' Eq instances.

What you'd need would be a function of type `(Shape a, Shape b) => a -> b -> Bool` that can be used to compare any shape to any other shape. If you have such a function, you can use that to create an `Eq` instance for `Object`. However you won't be able to define such a function in a way that's consistent with the types' `Eq` instances.

Comment: What if I made instances of Shape instances of Typeable as well? Then I can obviously check that the types match before testing the equality of the values themselves. I guess the only problem then would be convincing the type checker?